# What is the purpose of "int[]" here: "std::void_t<int[static_cast<Int>(-1) < static_cast<Int>(0)]>;"

Tags: c++, sfinae, void-t

This is from an example from a tutorial on `std::enable_if`.

Here is more context:

```
// handle signed types
template<typename Int>
auto incr1(Int& target, Int amount)
-> std::void_t<int[static_cast<Int>(-1) < static_cast<Int>(0)]>;
```

[From](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/3777/enable-if)

1. Shouldn't `std::void_t` be accepting a type as template argument?
2. What is the purpose of `int[]` in this context?

Comment: `int[some_constant]` is a type (array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `static_cast<Int>(-1) < static_cast<Int>(0)` yields `true`, `int[static_cast<Int>(-1) < static_cast<Int>(0)]` leads to `int[1]` (`true` could be [converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `int` (and then `std::size_t`) implicitly with value `1`), which is an array type.

If `static_cast<Int>(-1) < static_cast<Int>(0)` yields `false`, `int[static_cast<Int>(-1) < static_cast<Int>(0)]` leads to `int[0]` (`false` could be [converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `int` (and then `std::size_t`) implicitly with value `0`), which is an invalid array type and [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) would discard the specialization from the overload set. (The size of [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) must be greater than zero (unless using in [new[]-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new))).

Comment: Why is `int[1]` valid and `int[0]` not?

Comment: @Ocro See the definition of array: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array

Comment: @Octo The size of [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) must be greater than zero (unless using in  new[]-expression).

Answer (score 3):

`int[0]` (`int[false]`) is ill-formed and rejected by SFINAE.

Probably more clear would be:

```
std::enable_if_t<static_cast<Int>(-1) < static_cast<Int>(0)>
```